# htaccess block referers with keyword

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that is getting hit had with referer spam from sites with a domain that is always:

```
http://scanner-{somethin-unique-here}.top
```

How can I use my htaccess file to block all referers from scanner-xxx.top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your site root .htaccess you can use this rule based on `HTTP_REFERER` variable to block but just remember those sites can change `HTTP_REFERER` at some point as well:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} https?://scanner-.*\.top [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Make sure this rule is right at the top as first rule.